# Авторизация android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, мне нужно, чтобы при первом входе в приложение пользователь использовал свой аккаунт google play и я мог получить хотя бы его почту. Возможно ли такое, если да то наведите на мысль или подскажите пример реализации.

Comment: Да, можно. Почитайте доки гугла на счёт подключения авторизации. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id

Comment: если ответ помог, отметьте его как правильный, если нет, дайте об это знать , пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Настраиваем опции для входа :

```
   // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

Затем делаем GoogleApiClient

```
// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
// options specified by gso.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

А затем собственно вызываем activity авторизации

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start офф. документация, с нее стоит начать.